# Cannot the entire object from nested object json based on a key value match

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a data which is a nested json. It contains some objects with count 0 which needs to be removed from the JSON. The data is given below

```
const data = {
  "name": "A",
  "desc": "a",
  "count": 2,
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "A1",
      "desc": "a1",
      "count": 2,
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "A1-sub1",
          "desc": "a1-sub1",
          "count": 2,
        },
        {
          "name": "A1-sub2",
          "desc": "a1-sub2",
          "count": 0,
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "A2",
      "desc": "a2",
      "count": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Here the object **A1-sub2** and **A2** has count 0 which needs to be removed. 
I tried to delete the entire object but its not working. My code is as follows :

```
const deepCopy = (arr) => {
  let copy = [];
  arr.forEach(elem => {
    if(Array.isArray(elem)){
      copy.push(deepCopy(elem))
    }else{
      if (typeof elem === 'object') {
        copy.push(deepCopyObject(elem))
    } else {
        copy.push(elem)
      }
    }
  })
  return copy;
};
const deepCopyObject = (obj) => {
  let tempObj = {};
  for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
      if(key === "count"){
        if(obj[key] === 0){
          Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) { 

            delete obj[key]; 
            });
        }
      }
    if (Array.isArray(value)) {
      tempObj[key] = deepCopy(value);
    } else {
      if (typeof value === 'object') {
        tempObj[key] = deepCopyObject(value);
      } else {
        tempObj[key] = value
      }
    }
  }
  return tempObj;
};
console.log(deepCopyObject(data));
```

The expected outcome should be

```
const result = {
  "name": "A",
  "desc": "a",
  "count": 2,
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "A1",
      "desc": "a1",
      "count": 2,
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "A1-sub1",
          "desc": "a1-sub1",
          "count": 2,
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Assuming the structure is static and nests no further, this works.

```js
const data = {
  "name": "A",
  "desc": "a",
  "count": 2,
  "children": [{
      "name": "A1",
      "desc": "a1",
      "count": 2,
      "children": [{
          "name": "A1-sub1",
          "desc": "a1-sub1",
          "count": 2,
        },
        {
          "name": "A1-sub2",
          "desc": "a1-sub2",
          "count": 0,
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "A2",
      "desc": "a2",
      "count": 0
    }
  ]
};

data.children = data.children.reduce((acc, child) => {
  if (child.count !== 0) {
    if (child.children) {
      child.children = child.children.reduce((nestedAcc, nestedChild) => {
        if (nestedChild.count !== 0) {
          nestedAcc.push(nestedChild);
        }
        return nestedAcc
      })
    }
    acc.push(child);
  }
  return acc
}, []);
console.log(data.children);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of 2 look alike functions, you can do this in just one function.

The only problem with this function is that it reverses orders of keys of objects. If you don't need it in same order, then this function is fine.

```js
const filterObject = (obj) =>
   Object.keys(obj)
  .slice(0)
  .reduce((accumulator, currentKey, _currentIndex, array) => {
    if (obj.count === 0) {
      array.splice(1);
      return null;
    }

    if (currentKey === "children") {
      accumulator.children = [];

      for (let subObj of obj.children) {
        if (!subObj["children"]) {
          if (subObj.count > 0) accumulator.children.push(subObj);
        } else {
          let filtered = filterObject(subObj);
          if (filtered) accumulator.children.push(filtered);
        }
      }
    } else accumulator[currentKey] = obj[currentKey];

    return accumulator;
  }, {});

const data = {
  name: "A",
  desc: "a",
  count: 2,
  children: [{
      name: "A1",
      desc: "a1",
      count: 2,
      children: [{
          name: "A1-sub1",
          desc: "a1-sub1",
          count: 2,
        },
        {
          name: "A1-sub2",
          desc: "a1-sub2",
          count: 0,
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      name: "A2",
      desc: "a2",
      count: 0,
    },
  ],
};

console.log(filterObject(data));
```

Comment: we get empty arrays if we have two count 0 objects inside a children array. Try the below data as input

Comment: {
  name: "A",
  desc: "a",
  children: [{
      name: "A1",
      desc: "a1",
      count: 2,
      children: [{
          name: "A1-sub1",
          desc: "a1-sub1",
          count: 2,
        },
        {
          name: "A1-sub2",
          desc: "a1-sub2",
          count: 0,
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      name: "A2",
      desc: "a2",
      count: 0,
      children: [{
        name: "A2-1",
        desc: "a2-1",
        count: 0
      },
      {
        name: "A2-1",
        desc: "a2-1",
        count: 0
      }
      ]
    },
  ],
};

Answer (score 0):

beacuse you are deleting from obj not from tempObj which you are returning

```
 if(obj[key] === 0){
      Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) { 

        delete obj[key]; 
        });
```

Following code is working for me

```
 const deepCopy = (arr) => {
let copy = [];
arr.forEach(elem => {
  if(Array.isArray(elem)){
    copy.push(deepCopy(elem))
  }else{
    if (typeof elem === 'object') {
      copy.push(deepCopyObject(elem))
  } else {
      copy.push(elem)
    }
  }
})
return copy;
};

   const deepCopyObject = (obj) => {
let tempObj = {};
for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    if(key === "count"){
      if(obj[key] === 0){
        tempObj = null;
      }
    }
  if (Array.isArray(value)) {
    tempObj[key] = deepCopy(value);
  } else {
    if (typeof value === 'object') {
      tempObj[key] = deepCopyObject(value);
    } else if(tempObj != null) {
      tempObj[key] = value
    }
  }
}
return tempObj;
};

const noNull = (v) => {
  if (v && typeof v === 'object' && Array.isArray(v.children)) v.children = 
 v.children.filter(noNull);
  return v !== null;
 };


const input = require('./input');
const data = [deepCopyObject(input)];

console.log(JSON.stringify(data.filter(noNull)));
```

input is the data that you provided